# Search and Replace text between curly brackets (VS Code)

Tags: regex, visual-studio, select, search, replace

I've been searching for ages how to replace text between brackets in VS Code. Here's an example or a file I want to replace content in:

```
capital = 267
oob = "AFG_1936"
set_technology = {
 CAS1 = 1
 CAS2 = 1
 CAS3 = 1
 CAS4 = 1
 radio_detection = 1
 rocket_engines = 1
 sp_rocket1 = 1
 sp_rocket2 = 1
 strategic_bomber1 = 1
 strategic_bomber2 = 1
 strategic_bomber3 = 1
 suicide_craft = 1
 synth_oil_experiments = 1
 tactical_bomber1 = 1
 tactical_bomber2 = 1
 tactical_bomber3 = 1
 tank_landing_craft = 1
 transport = 1
}
add_ideas = {
    population_growth_rapid
}
set_convoys = 200
...
```

I would like to replace, or at least select, what is between "set_technology = {" and its closing bracket.
I tried to search for "{.*}", or things like "{*.+[^\n]+}" but nothing seems to work...
If necessary, I can switch to Visual Studio 2017

Thanks in advance,
Stuffi

Comment: Not sure about Visual studio, but you could try  [`set_technology = {\K[^}]+`](https://regex101.com/r/3GR2Xw/1) or 
[`set_technology = {([^}]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/3GR2Xw/2)? or [`(?<=set_technology = {)[^}]+`](https://regex101.com/r/3GR2Xw/3)

Comment: Try to use `set_technology = {[\s\S\r]*?}`

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor!!! It works!!

Answer (score 1):

This regex is the solution:

```
set_technology = {[^}]*?}
```

Applied to your text, it gives one match. It has three parts:

`1. set_technology = {`

`2.[^}]*?` : All characters except `}` as *few* characters as possible. (`lazy quantifier`)

`3. }`

We need to use `lazy quantifier` "`*?`" and not `greedy quantifier` "`*`". `lazy quantifier` try to capture as few characters as possible. We want to stop capturing text after the first `}` and not the last `}`.

If we used `greedy quantifier` the match would contain:

```
set_technology = {
...
}
add_ideas = {
...
}
```

But with `lazy quantifier` it contains only:

```
set_technology = {
...
}
```